# What are some of the reliable color sensor circuit?

Tags: arduino, sensor

We want to detect four different colors:

1. Red
2. Blue
3. Green
4. Yellow

There are many different color sensor circuits using photodiode and LDR available in the internet. What are some of the reliable circuits which doesn't get affected by the ambient light also. The controller used is arduino.

Comment: Since life it is not becomes easy even with Arduino, please decide what is the main parameter of your application: Response to light changes, low light response, good linearity, easy calibration, accurate response to wavelength...what? As far as I know the LDRs used in photometry, and nice source for (even free of charge) pricise filters are available from LEE  http://www.leefilters.com/lighting/colour-details.html#182

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to detect the color of a nearby surface?

My suggestion is to use a light sensor with a flat response over the colors, and 4 LEDs. Light up each LED in turn, and see how much difference that makes in the light sensor reading. You'll have to calibrate for the effectiveness of each LED.

IME an LDR is usable, but it is rather slow.